# Getting "Illegal char <>>" when pulling git code

Tags: git

I am trying to pull the latest code from git, but it is showing the error below:

[image]

I went to the path it shows, but I didn't find a file with that name.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `>` is an illegal file/path character on Windows, but not on Linux.

Comment: So how to solve the issue?

Comment: You could tell the owner of the Git repository about the problem and ask to rename it or use Linux yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete/rename the branch `Actions-->PathMenu-->ShowCktRelationships` from your `origin` remote.